# How do you specify the type of a value in a keyof declaration?

Tags: typescript

I have a simple sum function that takes two arguments, an iterable data structure and a key whose value will be summed:

```
const sum<T, K extends keyof T>(arr: T, key: K) => {
  return arr.reduce((acc, el) => {
    acc += el[key]
    return acc
  }, 0)
}
```

const data = [{value: 3}, {value: 1}, {value: 2}]

sum(data, 'value')

I want to be able to tell typescript that the key's value is of type number. How can I do this in Typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably meant to write `arr: T[]`. You also need to let TS know that for the key `K`, you will get back a number. You can do this by constraining `T` to extends `Record<K, number>`

```
const sum = <T extends Record<K, number>, K extends keyof T>(arr: T[], key: K) => {
  return arr.reduce((acc, el) => {
    acc += el[key]
    return acc
  }, 0)
}

sum([
  { value: 1, other: "" },
  { value: 2, other: "" },
], 'value')

const v = [
  { value: 1, other: "" },
  { value: 2, other: "" },
]
sum(v, 'other') // error
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=17&ssc=25&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCuBbGBeGAeAKjApgDyhzABMIYAlHUAJ2PQGkAaGMJAIx2oD5n7cCipGAGscATxAAzGJi4AKAIbVqALhkBtALrNRYtfQCUqLjADeAWABQMGNRxR41MDCXUAdHeLxgOOYuDAzDgANkYoJhbWNi4BMADUaCHquppW0bb2js4KAWkwAL7MAAwGVvlWVgiIcup5pjAAbgrB8DhqAIzMIFAAFpxqAEQDBYx1jc2tagBMXb39MEMjVtowAORNLTirpZZWoJCwDagwtVH1G5MwnTDdfaoLw4VjF20wMzdz94tPlqmWVXIGsxVrdONsYAB6CG4ZQgahAA)